# Is it possible to renounce the key property of a Olingo EntityType

Tags: java, odata, olingo

Is a key value mandatory while setting up an [EntityType](http://olingo.apache.org/javadoc/odata2/org/apache/olingo/odata2/api/edm/provider/EntityType.html)?

This may sound a little odd but I have a case where a key is unnecessary. So I was asking myself if I can get rid of these code lines.

```
        List<PropertyRef> keyProperties = new ArrayList<PropertyRef>();
        keyProperties.add(new PropertyRef().setName("KEY"));
        Key key = new Key().setKeys(keyProperties);
```

Comment: I haven't worked with Olingo, but what I remember from working with OData: if it's an entity, it always has a key. If it doesn't have a key, then you can model it as an OData complex type instead of an entity type.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A key is required for an `entityType` in olingo and odata, because if there is no unique key for an entity then we won't be able to use `getEntity` (to query the data of just one entity from a given `entitySet`) on it , as well as navigation properties and `$expand`  will also not behave properly.